# Separate dll in an ASP.NET webform + MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, dll, webforms

I have an asp.net webform website and added a new part in asp.net MVC 1.0.
For an easy maintenance I would like to separate the code into 2 dll, one for webform part and second for MVC part.
If my website is named 'TheWeb', then I only get a single dll named TheWeb.dll

Is it possible and how to proceed ?

Thanks
Sinn'

Answer (score 0):

In your solution add a second project. You get a DLL for each project.

Comment: Not necessarily,, you can put all the codebehind of the webfrom in a class library. And then in the .aspx page you link the code to the other project where the codebehind of this resides. I don't know for sure it this will work.